# jQuery Sortable with Ajax and mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

Hey I've created a sortable list for the backend of my site to organize my categories and I have it all working so it runs an update SQL statement with Ajax and it saves my data without a reload, but the order number that I'm displaying in my backend from the database doesn't change until I reload, any help would be great, thanks in advance!

PHP

```
        <?php
    $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_slug, cat_status, cat_order, sta_id, sta_name
            FROM app_categories LEFT JOIN app_status
            ON app_categories.cat_status = app_status.sta_id
            ORDER BY cat_order ASC";

        if($result = query($sql)){
            $list = array();

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                array_push($list, $data);
            }

            foreach($list as $i => $row){ 
            ?>
                <div class="row" id="page_<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>">
                    <div class="column two"><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></div>
                    <div class="column two"><?php echo $row['cat_slug']; ?></div>
                    <div class="column two"><?php echo $row['cat_status']; ?></div>
                    <div class="column two"><?php echo $row['cat_order']; ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "FAIL";
        }
    ?>
```

jQuery with Ajax call

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu-pages").sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
                $.post("ajax.php", {  type: "orderPages", pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize') } );
            }
        });
    });
```

And my ajax.php which does my update

```
<?php

parse_str($_POST['pages'], $pageOrder);

foreach ($pageOrder['page'] as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE app_categories SET `cat_order` = '$key' WHERE `cat_id` = '$value'";

    if(query($sql)) {
        echo "YES"; 
    }
    else {
        echo "NO";  
    }

}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have any kind of code for handling the front-end update. The easiest thing to do would be to add a callback in your ajax post and have the server send back the update information as json data.

So ajax.php would look more like

```
<?php

parse_str($_POST['pages'], $pageOrder);

foreach ($pageOrder['page'] as $key => $value) {
$sql = "UPDATE app_categories SET `cat_order` = '$key' WHERE `cat_id` = '$value'";

if(query($sql)) {
    $orderSql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_slug, cat_status, cat_order, sta_id, sta_name
        FROM app_categories LEFT JOIN app_status
        ON app_categories.cat_status = app_status.sta_id
        ORDER BY cat_order ASC";

    if($result = query($sql)){
          echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
          return;
    }

} else {
    echo json_encode( array('result' => 'failure'));
}

}
```

(Yeah, it's ugly and untested but you get the idea.)

Your javascript would then look something like

```
    $.post("ajax.php", {  type: "orderPages", pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize') }, function(res){
         if (typeof res.result !== undefined && res.result === 'failure'){
              alert('failed!');
               return;
         } else {
              $.each(res, function(i, item){
                     $("#page_" + item.cat_id).find('div:eq(3)').html(item.cat_order);
              });
     }, 'json' );
```

Which again is terrible, but hopefully conveys the point.

Alternatively you could simply update the number in the sort div whenever it is moved. That would look like:

```
   $("#menu-pages").sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            $.post("ajax.php", {  type: "orderPages", pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize') } );
            $('.row').each(function(i){
                 $(this).find('div:eq(3)').html(parseInt(i) + 1);
            });
        }
    });
```

Also not test, and that's assuming cat_sort is 1-indexed and not missing any values etc etc.